# Is it possible to use both CakePHP default auth with the hybrid Auth?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, hybridauth

Right now I am working on project where we need facebook and twitter login.
And I have also configure the login in my project but now its not authenticate with simple username and password.

This is AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
            $this->loadComponent('Flash');
            $this->loadComponent('Auth', [     
                'loginRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ],
                'logoutRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login'
                ],
                'authenticate' => [
                        'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth'
                ]
            ]);        
    }
}
```

Its working with only facebook and twitter login,and please let me know how to store user in database after successful login in fb or twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Change above function to this.

```
   public function initialize()
    {
            $this->loadComponent('Flash');
            $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'authenticate' => [
                        'Form',
                        'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth'
                ],
                'loginRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'index',
                    'plugin' => false
                ],
                'logoutRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login',
                    'plugin' => false
                ]
            ]);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The point here is: just add "Form" under "authenticate". 
CakePHP can handle many login types simultaneously. 
To store your users in the database just follow the plugin's instructions to set up the users and social_profiles tables.
Then simply add your regular user logic (UsersController + login.ctp, etc, etc).

Here's how I load the Auth component to achieve this:

```php
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email', 
                'password' => 'password'
            ],
        ],
        'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth' => [
            'fields' => [
                'provider' => 'provider',
                'openid_identifier' => 'openid_identifier',
                'email' => 'email'
            ],
            'profileModel' => 'ADmad/HybridAuth.SocialProfiles',
            'profileModelFkField' => 'user_id',
            'hauth_return_to' => null
        ],
    ],
]);
```